# Where did the word 'Wheelbarrow' come from?

Tags: history

I'm fairly confident that it's not a mangled 'Wheeled Barrel'.  I've heard of barrows in reference to deep graves, or underground storage chambers.

Answer (score 8):

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barrow):

> Origin of BARROW
>
> Middle English *barew*, from Old English *bearwe*; akin to Old English *beran* to carry — more at [bear](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear)
>   First Known Use: before 12th century

The addition of "hand" or "wheel" serves to indicate how it is moved along.

Answer (score 5):

Another definition of barrow is an apparatus for carrying things.  The OED gives this:

> A utensil for the carrying of a load
>   by two or more men; a stretcher, a
>   bier; spec. a flat rectangular frame
>   of transverse bars, having shafts or
>   ‘trams’ before and behind, by which it
>   is carried; sometimes with four legs
>   to raise it from the ground. Now more
>   usually called *hand-barrow* to
>   distinguish it from the *wheel-barrow*.

Looks like the early wheel-barrows where stretchers or shallow boxes (upon a single wheel).

Answer (score 2):

They are two different words - that just happen to have ended up with the same spelling.

barrow (1) "vehicle for carrying a load," c.1300, barewe, probably from an unrecorded O.E. *bearwe "basket, barrow," from beran "to bear, to carry"

barrow (2) "mound," O.E. beorg (W.Saxon), berg (Anglian) "barrow, mountain, hill, mound," from P.Gmc. *bergaz (cf. O.S., O.Fris., O.H.G. berg "mountain," O.N. bjarg "rock"), from PIE base *bheregh- "high, elevated"

(http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=barrow)

Answer (score 0):

The distinguishing mark of a *wheelbarrow*, as opposed to the ordinary barrow or handcart used by street vendors including sweet Molly Malone, is that it has only one wheel.